# Set emptyView of android listActivity

Tags: android

i have created a My custom listActivty by extending ListActivity like this.

```
public class MainList extends ListActivity {

ListView listView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    listView = getListView();
    setContentView(R.layout.list_main);

   }

}
```

And declaring its xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
</ListView>
<TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="My Text"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

i am using CursorAdapter as listActivity adapter.Its showing perfectly with MainList is empty.

My problem is that i want to show more than a textview when MainList is empty. Basically i need custom view(imageview,button etc) to be shown when list is empty.How should i do this.

Thanks

Comment: this is the code for everyone who might face this problem.

Comment: `     final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mycontext);
                final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_view, null, false);
                view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                ((ViewGroup)listView.getParent()).addView(view);
                listView.setEmptyView(view);
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the listview there is one default method to set empty view.

setEmptyView(view)

Try This.... In the place of view pass your custom view.

If you are not getting then tell me. I will post an example for this.

Comment: K. Check this www.androidcodesnips.blogspot.com here you will find android snips that are useful....

Answer (score 0):

You may want to count the items in your `CursorAdapter`. If 0 is returned, hide/show parts from your XML? That's how I done similar, but they may be better ways.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `android:id/empty` for your custom view. I think you can apply the id to any view, not just a `TextView`